# Does displaying of Android 2D Graphics use EGL library?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d

I would like to ask if Android always uses the EGL library for rendering 2D Graphics? Or it is using other libraries? I have noticed in the DisplayHardware.cpp and FramebufferNativeWindow.cpp that egl functions are always called when posting buffer etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this vid [Learn about Android Graphics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc) !

At 6:30 the graphics architecture is exdplained. I recommend watching the whole thing tough. Lots of useful information.

Comment: thanks for the link! It was really helpful. I would just like to summarize what I have learned from the video related to my question, android may use OpenGL(GPU or PixelFlinger) or 2D Blitter (MDP) for the rendering.